# Build less files command line

Tags: cmd, msbuild, less

Is there any way of compiling less files with the msbuild.exe?

How does the web essentials compiles less files within the visual studio when compiling the project?

Comment: Look at lessc, the LESS compiler.  There are also MSBuild tasks; Google it.

Comment: MSBuild task to compile LESS files http://www.marthijnvandenheuvel.com/2012/11/21/msbuild-task-to-compile-less-files/